# Modal always show in React Native

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I import Modal from 'react-native'

Here is my simple modal.

```
<Modal visible={false}>
<View>
 <Text>Hello modal</Text>
</View>
</Modal>
```

The visible is false, then again it's open on the screen.

Comment: Is there any other code that you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it will work. But I don't know, your exact scenario.

I would suggest using [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal), which is a very popular library and gets updated frequently. I'm sure it will work for all your scenarios.

If not, please revert back to me.

Comment: i tried this.
But , isVisible ={false} not working ..
it's always show in the screen.

Comment: Make sure the modal is inside a view. Can you please share your render function to get more about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

by default it the modal will be true, so you need to set it to be false

```
this.state ={ 
  modalOpen: false,
} 


  <Modal 
     visible={this.state.modalOpen}>
      <Text>Hello modal</Text>
  </Modal>
```

Comment: i used visile false !